# How to get access token using authorization code?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to develop an app which requires gmail authorization and authentication. using oAuth2 i have retrieved the authorization code but now how can i get the access token using this code...?? I am using javascript and html5 for this app.

Comment: For which platform? fb, linkedin or google or someother

Comment: actually my app needs to upload videos on youtube and for that gmail authentication is required.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all i have got answer to my question.

After getting success code, you need to Use encodeURIComponent to encode each and every field in the query and then send the post request.

e.g. - var post_data =  'client_id=' + encodeURIComponent(CLIENTID) + '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(REDIRECT) + '&code=' + encodeURIComponent(CODE) + '&grant_type=' + encodeURIComponent(GRANT_TYPE) + '&client_secret=' + encodeURIComponent(CLIENT_SECRET);

and u need to assign this to the data field in your post request.

Then only , you will be able to get the access_token. I have used this code in my metro app and now i am able to successfully log into my gmail account via my application.

Answer (score 0):

We need to send Post request which will include all the parameters like : client_secret, client_id, grant_type and code. Since my app is Windows 8 based,so before sending POST request you need to encode your parameters otherwise you wont get the token.